# Using matplotlib how could I plot a histogram with given data in python

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, histogram

here is the data:

```
111, 3  
122, 4  
155, 3  
192, 5  
11,  9  
123, 10  
120, 23
```

now how could I able to plot a histogram using this two set of data in `matplotlib`.
please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a barchart like this:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
x = [111,122,155,192,11,123,120,]
y = [3,4,3,5,9,10,23]
bar(x,y)
show()
```

gives:
[image]
Using `hist()` bins your data for you, so you would pass it your raw data, ie. it would look like this:

```
data = [111, 111, 111, 122, 122, 122, 122, 155, ...]
```

Comment: @abhisek - The above plot is a histogram.

Comment: i dont need any info about bar diagram. Please give me the codes for histogram only.

Comment: @abhisek - In an histogram the area of the bar is equal to the frequency of that data. It can be drawn as a barchart. Your data (appears to, although your question is unclear) contains frequency infomation, so the easiest way to plot it as a histogram is to do the above. I also explain that if your data is raw, you can use `hist()` and it will generate the histogram for you.