# Histogram from data which is already binned, I have bins and frequency values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

All the matplotlib [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html) with `hist()` generate a data set, provide the data set to the `hist` function with some bins (possibly non-uniformly spaced) and the function automatically calculates and then plots the histogram.

I already have histogram data and I simply want to plot it, how can I do that?! For example, I have the bins (half open ranges are denoted by the square and curved bracket notation),

```
[0, 1)   0
[1, 2)   3
[2, 3)   8
[3, 4)   6
[4, 5)   2
[5, 6)   3
[6, 7)   1
[7, 8)   0
```

Comment: you want `bar` http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps the weight parameter would be of help in your problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b= [5,3,4,5,3,2,1,2,3]
plt.hist(a,9, weights=b)
plt.show()
```

Or, as tcaswell said, you could just make a bar plot and change the x-axis.

[Using matplotlib how could I plot a histogram with given data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512425/using-matplotlib-how-could-i-plot-a-histogram-with-given-data-in-python?rq=1)

Is a link.

Answer (score 3):

Also, as an alternative (similar to Matlab), you can use `bar`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b= [5,3,4,5,3,2,1,2,3]
plt.bar(a,b)
```

[image]

Then, you can also add the title and other stuff and, finally, save the image:

```
plt.title("Clock cycles")
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Size of the matrices processed")
plt.ylabel("Clock cycles")
plt.savefig("clock_cycles.svg")
```

Comment: With histogram your bars lie between the ticks, which makes more sense since the labels are actually ranges. With `.bar()` the bars are positioned on the ticks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned plt.step here yet for making step plots...

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b= [5,3,4,5,3,2,1,2,3]
plt.step(a,b)
```